# Losing variables data when changing pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I am actually programming a container in React-Admin to use the photos I stocked in my database, and show them in a Carousel.

So my code looks like :

```
import get_two from ./get_two

const CarouselField = ({ source, record = {}}) =>
    <div>
        <Carousel {...{width: '220px', 
            height: '110px',
            wrapAround: true,
            renderBottomCenterControls: false}}>
            <img src={get_two(source, record)[0]}/>
        </Carousel>
    </div>;
```

So when I go on the page, the image is working, but when I go to another page, it says that get_two is undefined.

Comment: Certainly, get_two is undefined then. Just with that piece of code, we cannot really help you... Can't you provide more concrete stuff, like a fiddle or something?

Comment: I find out my error, it was stupid.
Sorry I'm new in code and on Stack Overflow I don't know all the website like jsfiddle